# Using file dialog to add various CSVs to append to an existing table in access

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

I am trying my hardest on a project and keep running into brick walls. I'm trying to get it to where i can browse for a file, import that file so that it can be added to a table. The file name changes weekly so i cannot just have access set a specific file name to import. it HAS to be a browse feature. I've tried many things, checked references etc etc. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command51_Click()
    Dim dialog As FileDialog
    Dim fileName As String
    
    ' Create a FileDialog object to open the file dialog
    Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    ' Configure the file dialog
    With dialog
        .Title = "Select Excel File"
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            ' Get the selected file path
            fileName = .SelectedItems(1)
            ' Import the data from the Excel file into your Access table
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "YourAccessTableName", fileName, True
            MsgBox "Data imported successfully!", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This is a code that was given to me as example to work with but everything i find online on how to fix this error is dated... using 365 version of access.

Also here is what my references look like:
[image: Access References]

Any and all help would be appreciated. I'm someone learning as i go on this project of 3 years. Constantly trying to add new things to make the end-user not have to work as hard. Thanks again!

Tried changing references, tried changing dims. Getting Confused

***EDIT/UPDATE***

Edit: Changed Title

Update:

So i now have, basically what i wanted to work.. EXCEPT if the file name changes number of characters... IT DOESNT WORK. I mean.. it kinda does. So by that i mean, it'll append the file to the table i need... BUT it puts ALL of the data in the first column (though it does seem to know the first row is fields separated by tab... BUT IT DOESNT KEEP THE TEXTQUALIFIER for whatever reason.

***Edit 4***

So its NOT THE FILENAME that's causing the issue. If the content is changed (despite being the same exact format/layout) then it messes up??

For instance, if i change a "117" to a "118" then it messes up and says "Unparsable Record"

Here is the current code

```
Private Sub Command51_Click()
    Dim dialog As Office.fileDialog
    Dim selectedFile As String
    
    ' Clears the "Catalog ID Imports" table before continuing
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * From [Catalog ID Imports]"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
    ' Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Set dialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    ' Allow the user to select only one file.
    dialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    ' Set the title of the File Picker dialog box.
    dialog.Title = "Select CSV File"
    
    ' Show the File Picker dialog box.
    If dialog.Show = -1 Then
        ' Get the selected file.
        selectedFile = dialog.SelectedItems(1)
        
        ' Call the function to append the CSV file to the table.
        If AppendCSVToTable(selectedFile, "Catalog ID Imports", "Catalog_ID_Imports") Then
            MsgBox "CSV file appended to the table successfully!", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "Error appending CSV file to the table!", vbExclamation
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function AppendCSVToTable(filePath As String, tableName As String, specName As String) As Boolean
    ' Append the CSV file to the specified table with a saved import specification.
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Use DoCmd.TransferText to import the CSV file with the specified specification.
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, specName, tableName, filePath, True
    
    AppendCSVToTable = True
    Exit Function
    
ErrorHandler:
    AppendCSVToTable = False
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Function
```

Thanks to everyone who is helping! I appreciate everything anyone can do!

Comment: Please tell us what the specific problem is.  Also, what is the reason for not being able to copy/rename the file to a well defined name so you don't need to us the file dialog to import.

Comment: User defined type not defined sounds like you need `Option Explicit` to me.

Comment: You don't have the correct reference set.  [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.filedialog)

Comment: Set VBA reference to **Microsoft Office x.x Object Library**

Comment: oh i just seen these comments! OK, i will try to answer and update everyone!

Comment: @freeflow 

I can't copy/rename the file, just because the client does not want the end user to have to edit anything outside of using the forms.. As soon as I reply to everyone, i will edit my post and show my progress

Comment: @user10186832 yes i corrected this!